# How do I get the positions of elements in a filtered array without a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I need to perform the following

```
let array = [1, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5]
var positions: [Int] = []
for (index, val) in array.enumerated() where val == nil {
    positions.append(index)
}
print(positions) //gives [2, 4]
```

without having to do a `for` loop. Is it possible?

Comment: Use `filter` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the `indices`

```
let array = [1, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5]
let positions = array.indices.filter{array[$0] == nil}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) the enumeration:

```
let array = [1, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5]
let positions = array.enumerated().compactMap { (offset, value) in
    value == nil ? offset : nil
}
print(positions) // [2, 4]
```

Comment: In this case `map` will work equally well I assume since `enumerated()` will never include a nil value?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: No, what would not work. `enumerated()` enumerates the offsets and values without any filtering, and the values are of type `Int?`. With `map()` the result would be `[nil, nil, Optional(2), nil, Optional(4), nil, nil]`

Comment: `map` will not work here as the required result isn't just transforming into another type but filtering as well. `enumerated()` doesn't work like `compactMap`, it will work as `map` providing a list of `EnumeratedSequence` where `Array` element can be an `Optional`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I was thinking about `filter` + `map`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Yes, one can think of compactMap as  “filter + map”